# setStyleGenerator depends on cell value

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin8

I need to know how to use grid's `setStyleGenerator` for each cell depends on its value.

For example: for number column, I want every minus value (less than zero) has red text color.

I already know how to setting style for entire column.

```
addColumn(...).setStyleGenerator(...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your grid bean (lets call it `GridExampleBean` for now) has a property/field of `number`, the following should accomplish adding the style name of "red" to your grid cell when that grid row's item numbner property is less than zero:

```
Grid<GridExampleBean> grid = new Grid<GridExampleBean>(GridExampleBean.class);
// you can also use the getColumn method too :  grid.getColumn("number").
grid.addColumn(...)
        .setStyleGenerator((StyleGenerator<GridExampleBean>) item -> {
    if (item.getNumber() < 0) {
        return "red";
    }
    return "notRed";
});
```